# Pandas len according to the given condition

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a column and i want to find the length which is between 10 and 100 (for ex)

```
len(data[ 10 < data['TAHSILAT_DEGISIM_DEGER'] <= 100] )
```

error is : 
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with `sum` for count only `True` values:

```
data['TAHSILAT_DEGISIM_DEGER'].between(10, 100, inclusive=False).sum()
```

Or your solution:

```
len(data[data['TAHSILAT_DEGISIM_DEGER'].between(10, 100, inclusive=False)])
```

Answer (score 0):

use len() with series data type [docs of len() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html)

```
data[ 10 < data['TAHSILAT_DEGISIM_DEGER'].str.len() <= 100]
```

or

```
 data[(data['TAHSILAT_DEGISIM_DEGER'].str.len()) <= 100 & (data['TAHSILAT_DEGISIM_DEGER'].str.len())>10]
```

Comment: Error :  Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Answer (score 0):

your error comes from the wrong way to use the filter with multiple conditions,
so you could use:

```
len(data[ (10 < data['TAHSILAT_DEGISIM_DEGER']) & (data['TAHSILAT_DEGISIM_DEGER']<= 100]) )
```